# Second Bloom for Tulips?

Tags: bulbs, tulips

Is there any way to get tulips to bloom again this year? I know some flowers bloom again if you take the dead flower heads off.

Mine were looking great until a squirrel came along and eat every single one, so now I just have a garden full of tulip stalks. :(

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm afraid not - sometimes a single bulb produces two flowers, but with tulips, that's rare, and those two both come up at once, not in stages. A bulb is a storage organ - while the leaves are present, the bulb stores energy within it from the leaves, and flower initiation within the bulb (for the following spring) is already formed by the time the leaves die back. Tulips, though, are not 100% reliable in terms of survival or flowering the following year, but now is the time to feed them with liquid fertilizer, weekly, whilst the leaves are present, to give them the best chance of maybe flowering next year. Sadly, none of this deals with the squirrel problem...

Comment: Many thanks for your informative answer. Will follow your advice, and make sure to protect them more next year!